# Upload a document to Socrata using REST API

Tags: rest, socrata, soda

I am attempting to upload a file to a socrata site using their REST API. The file(s) I am trying to upload can be access directly by my application and could be serialized, or I could point Socrata to a url. The rest of the datatypes I am using are pretty straight forward; strings, dates, ect. But I can't seem to find any documentation on how to upload a file using REST with Socrata.

Is it even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "official" way of uploading files to Socrata, hence no documentation. If you want to attach a file to the dataset programmatically, then what existing libraries (Java in this example) do is use the `/api/assets` endpoint (which, if I'm not mistaken, is what the UI uses for uploading documents) and do a multipart POST.

- [soda-java's SodaDll::addAsset()](https://github.com/socrata/soda-java/blob/0a49e8055a1405d2d717a8316b8cdf63fc7f6e2f/src/main/java/com/socrata/api/SodaDdl.java#L344-L368)
- [soda-java's HttpLowLevel::postFileRaw()](https://github.com/socrata/soda-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/socrata/api/HttpLowLevel.java#L525-L536)